# Combine Python List Elements Based On Another List

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists:

```
phon = ["A","R","K","H"]
idx = [1,2,3,3]
```

`idx` corresponds to how `phon` should be grouped. In this case, `phon_grouped` should be `["A","R","KH"]` because both `"K"` and `"H"` correspond to group 3.

I'm assuming some sort of `zip` or `map` function is required, but I'm not sure how to implement it. I have something like:

```
a = []
for i in enumerate(phon):
    a[idx[i-1].append(phon[i])
```

but this does not actually work/compile

Comment: Is `idx` sorted? Or could the indices appear out of order? E.g. `[3, 2, 1, 3]` to output `['K', 'R', 'AH']`?

Comment: Good question. It will always be sorted.

Comment: To properly use enumerate you need two variables: `for idx, val in enumerate(a_list)`

Comment: That's why I pointed it out in a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It can have bearing. OP has indices, but not indices of the indices. Can view my answer.

Comment: Just a tip for the future.

Comment: @EugeneK: actually, I missed that the OP used `enumerate()` in their own attempt and were not using the `(index, value)` tuples that produces properly.

Comment: @IanAuld: my apologies, I had actually missed the incorrect use of `enumerate()` in the question. Mea Culpa!

Comment: @MartijnPieters no worries :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the output after zipping:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

result = [''.join([c for i, c in group]) 
          for key, group in groupby(zip(idx, phon), itemgetter(0))]
```

`itertools.groupby()` requires that your input is already sorted on the key (your `idx` values here).

- `zip()` pairs up the indices from `idx` with characters from `phon`
- `itertools.groupby()` groups the resulting tuples on the first value, the index. Equal index values puts the tuples into the same group
- The list comprehension then picks the characters from the group again and joins them into strings.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> phon = ["A","R","K","H"]
>>> idx = [1,2,3,3]
>>> [''.join([c for i, c in group]) for key, group in groupby(zip(idx, phon), itemgetter(0))]
['A', 'R', 'KH']
```

Comment: I have a little twist, if you're up for it: If any of the values in `idx` is repeated 3 or more times, I want to eliminate that mapping, as it's probably an error. Is that possible?

Comment: The easiest solution would be to filter after creating the sublist but before joining the string together. The first step would be: `groups = [(c for i,c in group) for key, group in groupby(zip(idx, phone), itemgetter(0))]` then using filter: `groups = filter(lambda g: len(g) < 3, groups)` and then finally joining them together: `groups = [''.join(g) for g in groups]`

Comment: @justanr: take into account that `g` here is then an iterable (a generator), not a sequence, and that `len()` won't work.

Comment: @Adam_G: justanr is correct, best to filter *after* the fact: `result = [g for g in result if len(g) < 3]` filters the results produced by my answer on length. You can integrate this into the first list comprehension but it'll get somewhat ugly.

Comment: So how do I get around the fact that `g`, a generator, has no `len()` function?

Comment: @Adam_G in my sample `g` is a string and not a generator any more.

Comment: @Martin Pieters: Oh duh. A simple conversion to list would fix that. My bad, I was up late commenting

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use an extra class:

```
phon = ["A","R","K","H"]
idx = [1,2,3,3]
a = [[] for i in range(idx[-1])] # Create list of lists of length(max(idx))
for data,place in enumerate(idx):
    a[place-1].append(phon[data])
```

[['A'], ['R'], ['K', 'H']]

Mainly the trick is to just pre-initialize your list. You know the final list will be of the max number found in idx, which should be the last number as you said idx is sorted.

Not sure if you wanted the end result to be an appended list, or concatenated characters, i.e. "KH" vs ['K', 'H']